# New water heater sometimes cold, sometimes hot

Tags: electrical, plumbing, water, heater

I have a new electric water heater (a week old). It does not operate correctly.  It took nearly 24 hours initially before there was any hot water. Then we had hot water for maybe half a day. Then cold again. Hot again the next day for a few hours.  Yesterday it was hot all day. Everyone got a shower. The dishes where caught up, then last night it was cold again, and is still cold this mornimg. What could possibly be wrong? I can't figure this one out.

Comment: Sounds like a Katy Perry song...
Your best bet is to take it back to the store or try to contact the customer service line. Attempting user service may void the warranty, and there is no good reason a brand new water heater should be having problems like this.

Comment: Call the customer support line for sure.  They can send replacement parts - they're not going to expect a customer to drain and return a heater that's already been installed.  An electric heater is a simple appliance, and should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Most water heaters upon initial start-up can take several hours to heat the tank water to the setting on the thermostat. Also, if the setting is not at the hottest temperature and it is a large tank 12 hours isn't unreasonable.

You should also be aware that if the entire tank of hot water is consumed for say a long shower it will take the incoming water awhile before it is heated to the set temperature.

If you still feel that there is something mechanically at fault with the new water heater than there is only very few parts that can not function. The first is the thermostat that controls the water temperature. You may have one that is faulty or intermittent. Second is the heating element(s). These actually are responsible for heating the water. They work by becoming extremely hot when electricity is applied to there terminal ends. The heat is then transferred to the surrounding water until the thermostat switches the power off at the proper setting. Heating elements will fail eventually and need to be replaced with one of the same **wattage** rating.

Since the appliance is so new and working on it will void the warranty (and can be dangerous) you should first contact the installer (if any). It is possible an installation step was over-looked. Next, contact the store from where it was purchased. Most reputable stores will readily accept a faulty appliance for refund with only a receipt of purchase.

Comment: A new water heater should have a recovery time in the 1-2 hour range.  If it's taking 12 hours to heat 40-50 gallons of water, there is something wrong.

Comment: Your comment would be more relevant (and I'd agree with it) if the OP's question had stated the capacity.

Comment: OP also failed to mention mode of install. Was this a DIY job and is OP qualified/competent? If it was a contractor or plumber then calling the installer would *absolutely* be the correct first move, as @ojait mentions.